# Redirect all urls with 'www' prefix for application with subdomains

Tags: django, url, gunicorn

I am working on a multi-tenant Django application where each tenant gets separate subdomain like
tenant1.example.com, tenant2.example.com etc.

As far as I know, usually www prefix in url is not used in subdomains. But I came to know that lot of my users actually add 'www' before any url. Many Tenant1 users enter url as www.tenant1.example.com which means that request doesn't come to actual site.

So, I am thinking of redirecting all the urls which have `www` prefix to respective subdomain url. I am not sure what is the best way. I can write a middleware which can do redirect, but I don't feel it's good to do so.

I searched but can't find the solution related to subdomain.

I am using Gunicorn, and currently hosting on Heroku. I can't find any server configuration related to above issue.

How can I solve above issue? I think configuring server would be the best, how do do that if it is possible?

Comment: Are you running gunicorn behind anything, such as nginx?

Comment: I am hosting on Heroku - as far as I know Heroku uses nginx for reverse proxy?

Edit: Heroku doesn't use nginx for Python deployments https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-faq#can-i-deploy-wsgi-python-web-applications

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by nginx or apache settings. Not on Django itself.

http://www.faultserver.com/q/answers-nginx-forward-all-subdomains-145141.html

Comment: I mentioned I am not using nginx or Apache in question.

Comment: I never used Heroku but it should also support subdomain redirection.